# Accessing derived members from a container of base pointers

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, containers

Consider the following code:

```
struct Object
{
bool hasComponent(std::string sComponentID);
Component& getComponent(std::string sComponentID);
std::vector<Component*> vComponents;
}

struct System
{
std::vector<Object*> vObjects;
}
```

My system will iterate over each Object in its vector and need to access data from derived members of Component (they all contain different state and data for the system to use).
I've considered something like this:

```
struct NetworkComponent : Component
{
std::string sID;
NetworkComponent(std::string tempID) : sID(tempID) {};

//Network data here
}

for(Object* p : vObjects)
{
     if(p->hasComponent("network")
     {
     NetworkComponent& network = static_cast<NetworkComponent&>(p->getComponent("network");
     //Access the data in the structure and do stuff with it.
     }
}
```

This does however feel VERY "hacky"; not to mention unsafe.
I was wondering if there is a better way to do things like this, or at the very least how to avoid this problem in the future?

Are there any good articles written on this subject that I can look up?
EDIT: dynamic_cast is NOT an option due to how slow it is.

Comment: You are very concerned with speed but you pass strings by value which may result in dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: This particular part of the program will be executed n times every frame at 60 frames per second where n is the number of objects, so yeah im concerned with speed.
Thanks for the heads up though, ill be sure to change it.

Comment: Component should have a virtual function for what you need to do. Needing to cast to a derived cast usually indicates bad design. But if you are sure the Component is a NetworkComponent, then I suggest you create a define which is dynamic_cast in debug mode and static_cast in release mode. For more checks in debug and more speed in release.

Comment: In this case, the component class and it's derivatives contain nothing but data where both the values and types varies from class to class, and I havn't been able to figure out a good way to access the data from the base pointer without having a huge overhead of virtual functions or involving usage of void pointers, which will just lead to even more casts anyways.

Comment: The point of polymorphism is you don't need to know the derived type at the time of use. It looks like you may as well store a union of possible pointers in your data structure.

Comment: How does hasComponent and getComponent work? You sure that check is more expensive than a virtual call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd refactor the `getComponent` method to return a pointer (a `nullptr` if no such component exists) instead of a reference and also pass the string argument with a constant reference:

```
Component * getComponent(const std::string & sComponentId);
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
template <typename CompType, typename ... Args>
CompType * getComponentOfType(Args && ... args)
{ return dynamic_cast<CompType *>(getComponent(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
```

If `dynamic_cast` is not an option here, use `static_cast`. By doing this you only lose a layer of safety for programming errors in this case.

And do something like:

```
for(Object * const p : vObjects) {
    assert(p);
    NetworkComponent * const net =
            p->getComponentOfType<NetworkComponent>("network");
    if (net) {
        // Use the network component.
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, I'll look into it more carefully when I get back from work, thanks a bunch!
Just out of curiosity though, what kind of programming errors would dynamic_cast prevent in this case?

Comment: Using `dynamic_cast` here _might_ help in case `getComponent` returns a pointer to an object not derived from the correct `Component` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to reinvent  [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast)

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but dynamic_cast is NOT an option because of the massive slowdown this will incur.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `class Object` to  contain *virtual methods*, which you want to have in derived classes.
Each of them should throw an exception, which mean *this object didn't redefined this method*.
Of course, in each of derived classes you should redefine methods that it's objects should have.